# what is the right way to do http request from within tomcat server

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat

i have tomcat server that holds web application i like to be able to call http requests from within this web application to other http server . what is the right way doing it ?
another impotent thing is that the web application needs to call multiple http request.
so i guess i need to use thread pool .
can tomcat give me thread pool or i need to build one .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [commons-httpclient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/). For thread pool use the [ExecutorService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) support provided in java 5.0.

It is same as how you would make http calls in any regular java app - running it in tomcat doesn't make it easier or difficult.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using something like [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html) or similar, rather than using raw Java APIs.